# Continue mouse press and release simulation while holding mouse click C#

Tags: c#, mouseevent

So what I mean is for example while holding LEFT_CLICK, simulate mouse click and release.

I tried this many ways but it tells my computer I unclicked and therefore, stops the loop.

```
if (Keys.KEYCLICKSTATE)
{
    Keys.mouse_event(Keys.MouseLeftDown, 0, 0, 0, new UIntPtr());
    Keys.mouse_event(Keys.MouseLeftUp, 0, 0, 0, new UIntPtr());
    Thread.Sleep(25);
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: sure, give me a minute.

editing post!

Comment: @PaulRooney done

Comment: Looks more like C# to me.

Comment: C++ and C# are different languages. Please tag accordingly.